# /rest/default/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/totals-information 404 magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, api, 404

when Visitor add a product to cart.

> Go to Cart Page.
>
> Click on Proceed to Checkout
>
> Login Pop-up will prompt to login.

When try to login it shows alert box with error

```
"No such entity with 
%fieldName = %fieldValue".
```

However we successfully logged into website but prior login show the above error and in console shows 404 error.

**Note: Guest Checkout is disabled in our site.**

Please suggest a solution.Thanks

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: i fixed this,go to reference link:https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/30758#issuecomment-777643269

Comment: I tried it but with no success, thanks.